# How to cross compile qt application for arm-v7

Tags: linux, qt, arm, embedded-linux

I have got a banana pi ARM v7 development board.I have successfully compiled a project on board.But how can I cross compile it on x86 Linux PC？Where to find tool-chain for banana pi or how can I build it by myself？
Thanks！

Comment: Please provide more details. Show your research so far!

Comment: Tell us what you have already tried and what is not working. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I have used [ScratchBox](http://www.scratchbox.org/documentation/user/scratchbox-1.0/html/tutorial.html) in the past to do the same thing in reverse in the past.  Just download it to the ARM host, and then follow the [Qt instructions](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qt-embedded-crosscompiling.html) on using a cross-compiler.